# Change String "@patient" to variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How can i use strings as varibles in ruby and assign values to it for eg:

```
"@" + "Patient".downcase = Patient.all.last
```

Thanks!

Comment: A hash might be a better option to store those values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you mean instance variables, you can do this:

```
instance_variable_set('@' + 'Patient'.downcase, Patient.last)
```